# ¿Es posble crear un array dinámico o automático en javascript?

Tags: javascript, array

El problema es poder crear un array donde por ejemplo se introduzcan valores de un input de tipo texto y se pueda crear un nuevo array, no sobre escribir el array, sino crear cada uno sin límites o según cada dato que se quiera insertar. Ejemplo:

```
array_1 = ['Hola'], array_2 = ['Hola de nuevo'], array_3 = ['Etc'].....
```

¿Puede haber alguna manera de iterar el nombre del array?
No es crear un array multidimensional o recorrerlo, sino crear X cantidad de arrays con un solo dato por ejemplo.

Otra forma de decirlo, lo que busco es es crear arrays con distinto nombre. Tal cual, array1, array2, arrayX... Y que cada uno tenga un valor distinto al pasarle Y valor.

Answer (score 4):

A lo que me da entender tu pregunta, necesitas un array que a su vez almacene arreglos cuantas veces se requiera. En el siguiente código se muestra como agregar arreglos a un arreglo principal por medio del metodo **push**.

```js
var array = [];

array.push(["nombre", "Fulano"]);
array.push(['apellido', "Sutano"]);
array.push(['edad', 34]);

array.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item);
});
```

Dentro de los arreglos, puede guardar cualquier tipo de dato o estructura. En el siguiente fragmento de código se muestra, por ejemplo, como guardar objetos dentro de un array ;

```js
var array = [];

array.push({nombre:"Fulano"});
array.push({nombre:"Sutano"});
array.push({nombre: "Mengano"});

array.forEach(function (item) {
  console.log(item);
});
```

Espero que esta respuesta te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Creo que no me di a enternder. Es crear arrays con distinto nombre. Tal cual, array1, array2, arrayX... Y que cada uno tenga un valor distinto al pasarle Y valor. No es recorrer un array o crear uno multidimensional.

Comment: Hola. Pues el problema está en que no puedo crear un array con push ya que me sobre escribe los datos anteriores y yo quiero que estos se conserven.  Hallé esta forma: https://jsfiddle.net/xb6n4p8z/1/

Answer (score 1):

No comprendo mucho lo que quieres hacer pero según veo quieres crear variables globales Javascript cada vez que el usuario por ejemplo presiona un botón se cree una nueva de tipo array ...

Inicio por comentar que no te recomiendo usar varias variables sino trabajar con objetos y cada nueva variables en realidad será una llave (Key) nueva en tu objeto.

Por ejemplo

```
Var Obj = {};
//Usuario ingresa una palabra 
Obj = $.extend(Obj, {array_1:['hola']});
//Usuario ingresa otra palabra 
Obj = $.extend(Obj, {array_2:['hola otra vez']});
```

Y para acceder a cualquier valor lo puedes hacer de las siguientes dos maneras

```
Obj.array_1;
Obj['array_1'];
```

PD. $.extend. Es una función del Framework jQuery que sirve para clonar objetos.

Disculpen los errores de formato y sintaxis pero estoy desde el teléfono.

Answer (score 0):

## Respuesta corta

Usa matrices anidadas e índices

## Explicación

Los elementos de una [matriz](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) (array) puede ser llamados usando un índice. Por ejemplo,

```js
/* Matriz unidimensional */
var reino = ["animal","vegetal"];
/* Imprime elementos */
for (var i = 0; i < reino.length; i++) console.log(reino[i]);
```

Además, los elementos de una matriz pueden ser otras matrices y estas, pueden llamadas usando índices de igual forma que se hizo en el ejemplo anterior. Para llamar a un elemento del "cruce" de una "columna" y un "renglón", usar sus "coordenadas" o "indices ortogonales" o de forma similar al ejemplo anterior:

```js
/* Matriz unidimensional */
var reino = ["animal","vegetal"];

/* Matriz bidimensional
 * Al primer nivel le llamaremos renglón, al segundo columna */
var especie = [["perro"],["árbol"]]; 
for (var i = 0; i < reino.length; i++){
  // Imprime encabezados
  console.log(" --- " + reino[i] + " --- ");
  // Imprime valores de las celdas de la matriz bidimensional
  for (var j = 0; j < especie[i].length; j++){
    console.log(especie[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Luego de leer un comentario del AP ahora entiendo que lo que está buscando es crear variables de forma dinámica, es decir, que sea el propio código el que asigne el nombre a la variables. Esto se puede hacer manipulando el objeto global

```js
// Creamos las variables de forma dinámica asignando una Array vacío.
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  this['miArray' + i] = [];
}

// A cada Array le agregamos un elemento
miArray0.push('Uno');
miArray1.push('Dos');
miArray2.push('Tres');

// Imprimimos en la consola cada una de las variables creadas y modificadas previamente
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  console.info(this['miArray' + i]);
}
```